# How to I return different type with __toString() method?

Tags: php, return, tostring

We use __toString() to returning class's default value like that:

```
<?php

class my
{
   public function __toString()
   {
      return "asdasd";
   }
}

?>
```

It returns only string type. But I want to return resource type:

```
<?php

class my
{
   public function __toString()
   {
      return imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");
   }
}

?>
```

It doesn't work.How to do it?Is there any method instead of __toString() or any way with using __toString?

Comment: It's called `__toString()` for a reason...

Comment: Why using __toString()? Isn't a method like getBinaryRepresentation() applicable?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please elaborate on "returning class's default value". Sounds like you want something similar to a COM/OLE/VisualBasic default property, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az06zx4y%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Nobody has given right answer yet.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration52.incompatible.php php removed the ability to return classes with tostring

Answer (score 12):

Suggest you write your own method `__toResource()` or similar. Trying to do this using `__toString()` would be wrong, as your not returning a String - you might confuse future developers or even yourself a year or so down the line.

Edit

In answer to your comment, like this?

```
// Use one _ as suggested by Artefacto
public function _toResource()
{
    // Return the resource object
    return imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");
}

public function __toString()
{
   // Return the filename as a string
   return "image.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Don't prefix method names with `__`. These are reserved and may be used in the future.

Comment: I am sorry. Is there any magic function called __toResource, or didn't I understand you well?

Comment: @sundowatch, no there isn't. Write your own. @Artefacto, good point. Use _ not __. I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @sundowatch: If I understand you correctly you want something like `imagesx( $yourObject );`. That simply won't work. There's no interface, no "magic" method that is used to cast object=>resource. All those built-in or extension module functions (I've seen so far) that expect a resource as parameter parse parameters via zend_parse_arg_impl() and for resources that function simply tests if the parameter _is_ a resource, no conversion.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. As the name says, `__toString` should return a string.

Not even something that is convertible to a string is allowed:

```
class my
{
   public function __toString()
   {
      return 6;
   }
}

//Catchable fatal error: Method my::__toString() must return a string value    
echo(new my());
```

If you are trying to have the contents of the image back when do do e.g. `echo(new my)`, you can do:

```
class my
{
   public function __toString()
   {
      return (string) file_get_contents("myimage.jpeg");
   }
}
```

Comment: You are right. But I will return image resource and than I will process this image like that:

$img = new my();
imagecopymergegray($dst,$img,0,0,0,0,0);
imagejpeg($dst,"image2.jpg");

I can't do it.

Comment: I don't want to file content. I want to image resource type.